# Why local variable defined in function 'getAr' is accessible in main?

Tags: c

```
int *getAr() 
{ 
         int *a; 
         int i; 
         a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10); 
         for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
            a[i]=i; 
         return(a); 
} 
int main() 
{ 
         int *a; 
         int i; 
         a=getAr(); 
         for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
            printf("%d\t",a[i]); 
         printf("\n"); 
         return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT is:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: what are you asking? YOu have a nice working program. getAr loads a dynamic array with 10 integers and returns it to main; main prints the array

Comment: Which local variable are you talking about? `int *a` is defined in both main and the function.

Comment: `main()` isn't accessing any local variable from `getAr()`. The returned value (pointer to memory location) from `getAr()` is a dynamically allocated memory location taken from heap. This allocated memory location is then assigned to `main()`'s local variable `a`. Therefore, `main()` is accessing its own local variable `a` in printing the `int`s stored in the memory location pointed by it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `malloc()`, the memory is taken from the heap. Which is not unloaded when the function returns (unlike the stack).

Comment: Agreed (and thank you very much), please answer the behaviour of this code also<br>
int *returnInt()<br>
{<br>
int a=20;<br>
return(&a);<br>
}<br>
int main()<br>
{<br>
int *a;<br>
a=returnInt();<br>
printf("%d\n",*a);<br>
}<br>
It prints 20 as an output. (gcc compiler)

Comment: ty @user3686233. You should create a new question for that.

Comment: that code is printing a random number that just happens to be the same as 'a'

Comment: @user3686233 - In this other code, the function is returning the address of its local variable `a`. The address is legitimate but it's already returned to the stack. Getting a printout of `20` is just a coincidence that the location hasn't been allocated yet for other variables. Between `a=returnInt()` and `printf(...)`, try inserting more local variables and initialize them and your chance of printing a 20 will lessen.

Answer (score 2):

*Others have already pointed out the reason, adding a few more points to help.*

Local/Automatic variables have their scope inside the function call, and not in any other function.

But here, you are returning the pointer to dynamically allocated memory, which won't be freed up after the function call, and this is the reason why the program works fine, in spite of the fact that there is a memory leak.

You will have to explicitly call **free()** to free up the memory you allocated using malloc().

I think you are confused in this case:

```
// When the array is on the stack:

int *getAr() {
    int b[10];        // 'b' allocated on stack
    int *a = b;       // 'a' allocated on stack
    return (a); // or return (b);
}

void main () {
    int * a = getAr();
    printf("%d \n", a[0]); // this may not give you the correct result
}
```

A good tutorial on stack and heap will help you:

http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Answer (score 0):

Its value is accessible inside main function because it is heap-allocated. Heap allocated data is accessible to any function in your program, opposed by stack-allocated data, which is accessible only to the function that created it due to stack unloading.

Source: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html#sec-3

Comment: Agreed (and thank you very much), please answer the behaviour of this code also
int *returnInt()
{
int a=20;
return(&a)
}
int main()
{
int *a;
a=returnInt();
printf("%d\n",*a);
}
It prints 20 as an output. (gcc compiler)

Comment: @user3686233 sorry, I don't get what you mean. When you return your variable, you are actually returning its memory address, which explains why you still can access the value previously stored there.

Answer (score -1):

Returning pointer to automatic local variable is not allowed in C as it does not exist once function returns.
Otherwise returning pointer to `static` local variable and variables that allocated dynamically is allowed.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated ?

Comment: Did you understand the question and then my answer ?